# How do you solve this issue with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Could you help me with this htaccess problem of mine?

My URL is:

```
mysite.com/blog.php?post=01/01/2012/my-first-post
```

And I want to transform it into this:

```
mysite.com/post/01/01/2012/my-first-post/
```

Which I partially solve this by using this:

```
RewriteRule    ^post/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    blog.php?postd=$1    [NC,L]
```

Now here comes the problem. When I try to click the second post "01/01/2012/my-second-post" which was suppose to go to

```
mysite.com/post/01/01/2012/my-second-post
```

but in return it goes to

```
mysite.com/post/01/01/2012/my-first-post/01/01/2012/my-second-post
```

Comment: This is not a .htaccess problem; rather your link is wrong. Change it to `/post/01/01/2012/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding in the header of all your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: thanks mate. i tried adding / in the href tag i never thought that it would cause a problem if there is no / there.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar with the site.

Comment: This will be a problem for some versions of IE, which require the `<base>` tag to contain an absolute URL.